# How do I pass an HTML element's value to a C# method in .cshtml?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor

I want to pass element from model to "setlaneOnFloor" method in .cshtml but error said they not exist.

```
<script>
function setlane(){
let floor = document.getElementById("floor");
let lane = document.getElementById("lane");
@Model.setlaneOnFloor(floor,lane)
}

</script>
```

```
[WebMethod]
public string setlaneOnFloor(int floor, int num)
{
return cmd.setlaneinsection(floor, num);
}
```

i also try this but i flews like I'm do something wrong.

```
<script>
function setlane(){
var data = { floor: document.getElementById("floor"), num: document.getElementById("lane") };
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: '\<%= ResolveUrl("\~/setlaneOnFloor") %\>',
data: JSON.stringify(data),
contentType: "application/json",
success: function (msg) {
$("#txtStartDate").val(msg.d);

}
});
}
</script>
```

I want to pass the element something like this
`@Model.setlaneOnFloor(5,6)\`

Comment: you wanna pass data from backend to javascript method directly?

Comment: What is your project type that have `WebMethod` attribute ? what is your framework?

Comment: for @XinranShen ,I want to pass data from frontend [HTML, JS] to backend [C#]

Comment: for @mamad2559 it's asp.net web application.I add WebMethod because i try to do ajax

Comment: You can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23076984/calling-webmethod-with-parameters-from-jquery-ajax-fails).